# how to select multiple matched entries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-aggregation

I have a PostgresDB where I have the below 2 tables

```
TBL_NODE_STG
NODE_NAME
NODE1
NODE2
NODE3

TBK_NODE_FINAL

NODE_NAME,PARTS
NODE1,PART1
NODE1,PART2
NODE2,PART2
NODE2,PART3
NODE2,PART4
NODE3,PART1
```

I need the output in the below format

```
NODE_NAME,PARTS,COUNT
NODE1,PART1|PART2,2
NODE2,PART2|PART3|PART4,3

select listagg( part,'|') within group(order by part),node_name,count(1) 
from TBL_NODE_STG
where node_name in (select node_name from TBL_NODE_FINAL)
group by NODE_NAME having count(1) > 1
```

We need to extract the PART from the TBL_NODE_FINAL and count the various nodes which are part of multiple PART

Answer (score 0):

try like below using sub query in postgre sql you can use STRING_AGG()

```
select STRING_AGG( PARTS,'|' order by PARTS),
a.node_name,count(b.PARTS) 
from TBL_NODE_STG a join
TBK_NODE_FINAL b on a.NODE_NAME=b.NODE_NAME
where exists ( select 1 from TBK_NODE_FINAL c
                  where c.node_name=a.node_name
                  having count(*)>1)
group by a.node_name
```

for oracle

```
select LISTAGG(PARTS,'|') WITHIN GROUP ( order by PARTS) as Parts,
a.NODE_NAME,count(b.PARTS) as cnt
from TBL_NODE_STG a join
TBK_NODE_FINAL b on a.NODE_NAME=b.NODE_NAME
where exists ( select 1 from TBK_NODE_FINAL c
                  where c.NODE_NAME=a.NODE_NAME
                  having count(*)>1)
group by a.NODE_NAME
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=741c031588382e9d12da237f21d87ad2)

Comment: @stacktesting how did you now it will not work ???

Comment: @stacktesting I have added demo for you

Comment: Sorry. Could you please provide the same for Oracle .

Comment: @stacktesting yes updated for oracle